# Filtering unanswered questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, tag-watching, ignored-tags

By default, the Unanswered section displays tags which are not included in my "ignored tags" list. I keep adding new tags to my ignore-list all the time, but since there are so many tags, I keep getting questions which I'm not interested in. Is there a way to achieve the "opposite behavior", meaning, that the page will display only tags that are under my "favorite" section?

**Update:**
I wanted to add a "motivation" section cause maybe the motivation for this FR it's not so obvious (like I originally thought):

If people would realize that by using all 5 tags - it would increase the chances of exposing their question to more potential answerers - everyone would benefit:
1. The OP would expose the question only to relevant members
2. The members would have easier time filtering relevant questions
3. The questions on SO would be sorted better and thus easier to search for

Comment: Are you using the "[My Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags)" option?

Comment: yes but it seems to display only older questions, and I want to search for the newest

Comment: Ah, yeah, My Tags has...I have no idea what it's sort order is, actually.

Comment: @BenBrocka further, clicking on a specific tag will display only new questions related to that tag, but I would like to view all the questions that are related to any of my favorite tags.

Answer (score 7):

I posted a feature request on this a few weeks ago: [Won't you let me view only my favorite tags, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138972/wont-you-let-me-view-only-my-favorite-tags-please) - apparently most people here either like the current behavior, don't care or perhaps don't visit Meta SO to express their opinion.

This my landing page - **HALF** of it - Firefox won't let me zoom out any further. Note the sidebar and my list of ignored tags. That is half the list. This is called *User Defending Against Poorly Designed User Interface*. Pretty ridiculous, isn't it.

In my question I asked for an explanation as to why the UI is set up this way but no one took responsibility for this UI design choice of forcing the use of explicit "ignore" tags in order to filter questions. Go figure.

[image]

Comment: iirc You can use [Awesome Screenshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/) to capture a full webpage at 100% zoom.

Answer (score 1):

> yes but it seems to display only older questions, and I want to search
>   for the newest

=> Yes Ofcourse its possible to find out Newest question. Have a look at below snap which i have captured for [android tag](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android) which is my favorite tag list.

[image]

Comment: I know that, plz read the last comment I wrote

Comment: Bhuro, Hope you can update your answer...!!!