# How do I *AND* my tags interests for filtering, while *OR* my tag-ignores?

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-filters

I know I must be missing a simple one-checkbox setting somewhere. i want to exclusively AND the criteria of my interested tag selections, while having a union OR of all my ignores. Such as.

Interests: c++ templates stl

Ignore java javascript .net

I want this to mean:

"show me only questions tagged with ALL tags in (c++ templates stl), and has no tag in (java javascript .net)"

I only ask this because honestly, people tag articles with things like c++ that have nothing to do with the context of their question other than it happens to be the language they're using when trying to solve their problem. The 'hit' ratio of actual technology associated questions significantly climbs once you start stacking the tags in a group.

So, is this even possible? Show me the checkbox!!

Comment: I'm really intrigued about questions that have **all** of c++ | templates | stl, and one of java | javascript .... (.net I could *just about* understand, thanks to C++/CLI - but a check says "zero" anyway ;p)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignored tag still shows up when using favorite tags with wildcards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138572/ignored-tag-still-shows-up-when-using-favorite-tags-with-wildcards)

Comment: And as always, I apologize for a duplicate if there was one. Thanks for the nudge in the right directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use plus to include it, and minus to exclude the term. These are the posts which include the C++, templates and stl tags, and not the Java/JavaScript/.NET tags:

[+[c++] +[templates] +[stl] -[java] -[javascript] -[.net]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++%20templates%20stl%20-java%20-javascript%20-.net)

Comment: When I leave out `[java]`, `[javascript]` and `[.net]`, I get the [same result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20templates%20stl). Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Thank you. This appears to work pretty well. Thank you.