# Filter questions on favorite tags but ignore those which have an ignored tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

Is there a way to view all questions on stack exchange which have a tag which I marked as favorite, *and* which do not contain tag which I marked as ignored?

I already have the filter for Favorite tags at https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags but could not find a way to also ignore the tags I marked as ignored.

Even filtering by my favorite tags, about half of the questions do not interest me. For example: I follow the *python* tag, and I know nothing about *windows*, so I still see many questions tagged both *python* and *windows* which I simply cannot answer.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140763/152859)

Comment: Questions in with tags from both filters are listed but displayed dimmed.  I think it's just a habit to get into to block those out mentally, though perhaps I get less than you in the tags I track.  However, wouldn't it be a shame if you missed something you could answer, just because somebody used the wrong tag?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I saw that question. By the question it is not clear if it is a dupe or not. I believe not, since he does not mention the favorita-tags url, and the only answer consists of using a long list of + or -, while I would want a list with only one plus and one minus: +favorites and -ignored.