# Tags I haven't answered in a long time should no longer be interesting

Tags: feature-request, interesting-page

The algorithm that generates the interesting top question tab should, over time, ignore topics I no longer answer.

For example, in my case I used to do iOS development, but haven't since about iOS 3. I haven't answered an iOS question in a long time. I no longer follow or have iOS tags marked as favorites, but interesting still gives me lots of iOS related questions because I used to answer them a couple years ago. I asked and answered a lot of iOS questions but have't for quite some time.

After a certain period of time of not answering questions, your interest in a topic should decrease. Therefore, they should show up less often on your interesting feed.

Comment: I totally agree with you. What would be a good time frame you think? Perhaps 365 days?

Comment: Yes please. I'm tired of seeing so much htaccess stuff everywhere I go. Answer a few questions and it haunts you for life!

Comment: In a more general case, it would be nice if we could *choose* the tags used by the algorithm. I understand this can seem counter-productive at first, but, to take my personal case as an example, I'm sometimes presented with a wall of `[jquery]` questions even though I'm also interested in many other tags. In the end, it actually makes it difficult for me to be more proficient in other, less popular tags.

Comment: You could always add `iOS` to your ignore list...

Comment: @Xarcell gradual or weighted?

Comment: I'm going to disagree. I like @FrédéricHamidi 's suggestion of being able to control the tags, but I bet there are plenty of people whose favorite tags are things they read about, *not* things they answer about. (FWIW, I'm *not* such a person, but I am sure they exist.)

Comment: I suspect [this](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow) will make itself useful very, very soon...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, that's actually part of why I even knew to think of this as a feature

Comment: @HamZa unfortunately the ignore list is less than useful - ironically [the ignored list is itself ignored when using wildcards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138572/ignored-tag-still-shows-up-when-using-favorite-tags-with-wildcards), for example.