# Black buttons look out of place

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design

I'm referring to those new big black buttons on Stack Overflow for actions such as "Post Your Answer", "Add Comment", "Add Another Answer", "Yes" and "No":

[image: a purple cat screams in the night]

Their high contrast and relief hurt the eye in an interface otherwise mostly soft.

The problem with spots of high differences of contrast is that it makes more difficult to see the rest of the page.

Comment: Yeah... mostly soft. There are dozens if not hundreds of these in the mod queue (more than in the 10k queue? I don't even remember what the 10k queue looks like anymore) - and over there it's *murder*.

Comment: @Bolt here's a [reminder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UktP2.png) :) (dystroy feel free to use this as another example in your post)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Ah. Ours has more buttons.

Comment: @Bolt poor mods! ;-)

Comment: Button: "I WANT YOUR ATTENTION!" Me: "No. I will have my coffee." Button: "YOU MUST REVIEW!" Me: "...okay then. One more." Button: "Mm. That's the ticket."

Comment: looks like developers at so  wants to design like new visual studio where everything is dark

Comment: @NullPointer You know there *is* a light theme for VS2012, right? And if they *really* wanted to design like VS2012, everything would be in uppercase. =D

Comment: @J.Steen being not a c# guy only know about [dark theme](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/6-Running-a-Windows-Store-App-in-the-VS-Tablet-Emulator.png)

Comment: @NullPointer Are you saying it sets up the dark theme as default if you're not a C# programmer? What? =D

Comment: Its an intriguing change considering fonts on stuff like votes and flat buttons have been "slimmed down" to save some bytes on css... doesnt this one run contrary to that?

Comment: @NullPointer: That's not even the dark theme! That's the light one!

Comment: It *is* a Call-To-Action, so isn't it better that it draws your attention to it?

Comment: @JonW There are too many Call-To-Action. Do I really need to **Add Another Answer** ? When can I stop adding answers ?

Comment: Surely someone will make a userscript for this before the GMT day ends.

Comment: I like the buttons. SE is primarily a Q&A site, so I think having the `Ask Question` and `Add Answer` buttons stand out more is a Good Thing :) Some of the other buttons could use some toning down though, such as the [Add] button for adding your favorite tags

Comment: Also, a brief glance at the comments in your screenshot lead me to some interesting first thoughts that required me to go back and re-read them more carefully - "I'll consider it" ... "destory" ... "hope you're serious" ... "my wife" :)

Comment: Ugh. This is a blight. Seriously, it looks like a cancerous mole.

Comment: I think it's the added emphasis given by the unnecessary capitals... If I only had to **Add another answer** it might be better than **Add[ing] Another Answer**?

Comment: We don't need to add "Eeeeek" on every issue just because it looks different.

Comment: Being a designer for Stack Exchange has to be the hardest job in the world :-)

Comment: I don't think so. Some of us often have a manager asking for another new button in the interface because of a new feature they want to sell and it ends [like this](http://24.media.tumblr.com/XgKk0gEJx69j7d22RcqfGoMU_500.png).

Comment: They are just some simple changes in the CSS - can be reverted easily with a bit of userscript.

Comment: @meta.michael You were right...

Comment: Considering how weak the site design is overall, complaining about a button is rather silly.

Comment: @random http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/166442/4 What's with the comment? :P

Comment: @skinnyTOD Let me disagree. Overall the interface is efficient. The new user can easily find and understand complex features and you can quickly parse questions and lists.

Comment: @dystroy - No, for all the bells and whistles, at its core it is horribly inefficient and inconsiderate of the user. Here is one glaring example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139774/182042

Comment: @Doorknob he means that it was one-time meme for the good old envelope R.I.P (see you joined after it was gone... in short it was something very important to many people that one day suddenly disappeared. Now that was a real Eeeeek)

Answer (score 7):

UserScript to bring back the plain button.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Plain Button
// @namespace      nhahtdh
// @description    Brings back the plain old button!
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include        http://stackapps.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include        http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include        http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include        http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include        http://mathoverflow.net/*
// @include        http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/*
// @exclude        http://chat.*/*
// @grant          metadata
// @author         nhahtdh

function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

with_jquery(function ($) {
    $('head').append(
        $(
            '<style>' +
            // Remove black buttons
            'input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { \
                box-shadow: inherit; \
                background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); \
                color: rgb(68, 68, 68); \
                border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153) !important; \
                border-radius: inherit; \
            }' +
            '</style>'
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: It seems to work.

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks for the feedback.